# xslt get parent node without child node from xml

Tags: xml, xslt

How can I get only parent node form xslt?

example : follwing xml file

```
<nums>
  <num>2.5
    <subnum>
      34
    </subnum>
  </num>
</nums>
```

I need to get only value 2.5 but when I wrote following xslt it gets both 2.5 and 34.

xslt code :

```
<xsl:element name="numbers">
    <xsl:value-of select="nums/num"></xsl:value-of>
  </xsl:element>
```

how can I get only parent value(without child node values) from xslt??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the value of the text node within your element, then you can specify that in your XPath query, e.g.:

```
<xsl:value-of select="nums/num/text()" />
```